# How to send data from controller to rest api in laravel?

Tags: laravel, api

How can I send data from controller to external api in Laravel?

```
public function syncData(Request $request)
{
    $datas = Data::all();
    $newDatas = NewData::all();
    $url = 'mydomain.com/api/sync-data';
}
```

I want to send `$datas` and `$newDatas` to `$url` through Laravel controller and perform some actions on those data. How can I achieve that?

Comment: you need to use `curl` for that

Comment: how to use curl a samle code will be helpful to me

Comment: see the answer section please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Laravel HTTP Client (which is a wrapper for Guzzle HTTP Client) to perform a request to that API.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::post('mydomain.com/api/sync-data', [
    'data' => Data::all(),
    'newdata' => NewData::all(),
]);
```

Comment: How will I echo data in external api?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by that. You may use the response variable to perform further steps and handle the APIs response. or are you in control of the „external“ API as well? Are you asking how to receive and handle request send from this snippet? That may be a completely other topic and you may want to open a new question...

Answer (score 1):

```
public function syncData(Request $request)
{
    $datas = Data::all();
    $newDatas = NewData::all();
    $url = 'mydomain.com/api/sync-data';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($datas));
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);  
}
```

let me know if it is helpful.
important things to notice here.
you have to know what your external API type is. is it POST or in GET method.
my example above is just a sample code to make you understand how you will use curl it is not tested in regard to your context

Comment: Can I dd this data in my domain?

Comment: dd what ? can you please explain more ?

Comment: I mean how can i verify if data is sent to url?

Comment: My method is type POST

Comment: well, in this case you have to know what your external API required. having said that I meant. what are the key value pair like name should exactly be same. you can look at it by reading the external API documentation. 
on the other hand, you can always dd your data before sending to curl.

Comment: This is the data I am retrieving from my localhost and want to save those data in server so I am sending these data to this rest api where  I can perform insert operation.

Comment: I understand what you mean by looking at your question only. and that's exactly what I am trying to explain to you. for example. your external api required 
name field to be `name` in this case you have to send name only. can not send any other name. that's how you can perform the insert operation

Comment: I want to send data in array and retrieve the data in my external api and do any kind of operation in my external api

Comment: Yes, then this is the code you have to use. try it. you can never tell what's going on without trying it on by yourself

Comment: I am newto curl and I tried the code but i don't know how to know if i received the data.

Comment: dd the variable `$output` that's how you will know if external API has receive the data or not, and wrap the code inside `try catch` block. will help you know what is the error

Comment: When I dd the variable $output, my port changed from 8000 to 8001 and can't run my application.

Comment: How can decode this value in my external api?

Comment: json_decode(??) I tried json_decode($request->datas)